# Why won't the Rails asset pipeline compile a CSS manifest when it's not called "application.css.scss"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Up until now all of my application's CSS has been served through `application.css.scss` which looks like this:

```
/* ...
*= require jquery-ui
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/

@import "bootstrap";
```

I recently needed to create a separate, stripped down manifest file that was to serve only a single embeddable asset in our website. Unfortunately though I couldn't get the CSS file to be packaged up and processed by the asset pipeline. It kept getting put into production with a URL that looked like this:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/minimag.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

rather than what it should have looked like with fingerprinting and precompliation which would be more like:

```
<link href="/assets/minimag-292d6edcd4fd2398abab273acf8.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

### On debugging I discovered that the manifest HAS to be called application.css

There's a good chance I'm missing something. BUT on stripping the problem back to its bare essentials I looked just at the application's stylesheet itself.

What I found was that when it was called `application.css.scss`, it was compiled just fine but when the name was changed it didn't get processed:

#### So this works:

*application.html.haml*

```
...
= stylesheet_link_tag "application"
...
```

together with a stylesheet called `application.css.scss`. In production this yields the inclusion HTML:

```
...
<link href="/assets/application-292d6edcd4fd6ec1da12b93fb273acf8.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
```

#### But this does not work

*application.html.haml*

```
...
= stylesheet_link_tag "testing"
...
```

together with *exactly the same* stylesheet but now renamed to `testing.css.scss`. In production this yields the inclusion HTML:

```
...
<link href="/stylesheets/testing.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
```

### What makes "application.css.scss" special?

Why is this going on? Why can't I just use a manifest file that has any old name?

(if it's at all relevant I'm deploying to Heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add stylesheets to the precompilation if you want to use them as a standalone file.

```
# config/environments/production.rb

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
config.assets.precompile += %w(testing.css)
```